# Change loop from every cell to particular range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, vba

I have the following piece of code which sends emails in bulk.

```
Sub Sengrd_Files()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim FileCell As Range
    Dim rng As Range
para2 = ""
para3 = ""

para232 = Range("AA2").Value

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
        Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMail
                .to = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Circle Profitability Report for the period ended 30-NOV-2017"
                .Body = "Dear Sir/Madam," _
& vbNewLine _
    & para232 & vbNewLine _
    & vbNewLine & para2 & vbNewLine _
    & Remark & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & para3 & vbNewLine & vbNewLine


                For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                        If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                            .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                Next FileCell

                .Send  'Or use .Display
            End With

            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

7 different mails will be sent to different people mentioned in Column B with Attachment defined in Col C.
The Macro by default sends mails for ALL line items probably because of this line in code

```
**For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)**
```

I cannot define a variable i and change the above line to

```
**For Each i =1 to 5 sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)**
```

due to syntax error. Can anyone help me in syntax in replacing "For each cell in" to a finite range.

Comment: Why does your code look like it was hit by a truck? At the very least, delete the excessive line breaks.

Comment: why would you want to use `i` variable ?

Comment: What makes you think that line is the problem? Have you tried stepping through your code to debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to make the bulk-mail-sender send only to a given range (in this case B2 -  B5):

```
For Each cell In sh.Range("B2:B5")
```

And do not forget - spam is bad.

Comment: @Michel - modify it without the `.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` part.

Comment: when i change to to" For Each cell In sh.Range("B2:B5").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)" it limits to B5 ,but sends the 1st mail 4 items :(

Comment: @Michel - when you write only `For Each cell In sh.Range("B2:B5")` it will send it to `B2`, `B3`, `B4` and `B5`. If you want to include `B6` then write `For Each cell in sh.Range("B2:B6")`. And **do not write** the `.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` part.

Comment: thanks a lot......should have avoided asking....i was so engaged in for i=1 to 5 for hours,that i almost forgot that  i could have modified  sh.Columns("B") in the next few words

Comment: @Michel - it is always good to ask, especially when you are giving your code & what you have tried so far.